# Number of SO(3) orbits

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, group-actions

Let $D^l$ be a $n=2l+1$ dimensional irreducible unitary representation of $SO(3)$. Then $SO(3)$ acts on the sphere $S^{2n-1}\subseteq \Bbb{C}^n$. ($D^l(R)$ is unitary $\forall R \in$ $SO(3) )$. Into how many orbits will  the sphere decompose?

Comment: How does $D^l$ act on $\Bbb C^n$? (Don't you mean the restriction of the representation to the unit sphere in $D^l$?) Do you suppose that $D^l$ has a metric and the representation maps $SO(3)$ to $O(2l+1)$? A lot of clerification is needed.

Comment: Hi Peter, I deleted the variable name $O(n)$ for the number of orbits, sorry, not a good name, maybe you thought of it as the orthogonal group ? Besides that, i think the question should be clear (?) since the number of orbits is independent of the explicit form of the $SO(3)$ representation.

Comment: To give an example, think of $D^l$ as the Wigner D matrix acting in the space spanned by the spherical harmonics. (And let $D^l$ act on the sphere in this space.) P.S: I read some literature about the topic, I guess the problem is more involved than I first thought..)

Comment: So $D^l$ is a complex irreducible unitary representation of $SO(3)$ of dimension $n$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: The question is courious :  if $n\geq 3$ you have an infinity of orbits. Do you means orbit type ? or number of strata in the strafications by conjugacy classes of isotropy subgroups ?

Comment: @Thomas: Intuitively I agree, since any orbit is by definition a 3D (sub-)manifold, parameterized according the three Euler angles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once $l>0$ there are infinitely many orbits just for dimension reasons:
$SO(3)$ is three-dimensional, but the unit sphere in ${\bf C}^n$ 
has dimension $2n-1 = 4l+1 > 3$.  Of course for $l=0$ the action is
trivial, so again there are infinitely many orbits.

Likewise, once $l>1$ there are already infinitely many orbits
for the action of $SO(3)$ on the unit sphere in ${\bf R}^n$,
which has dimension $n-1 = 2l$.  (For $l=1$ the action is transitive,
and for $l=0$ the action is trivial but $S_0$ has only two points
so there are two orbits.)

Comment: I think this precisely answers the question; however, I offered the bounty points to alain hoping that someone would give me more intuition on how these orbits look like. But probably this is hard to formalize..

Comment: I see that this was at least implicitly noted in the comments, yes.  It's probably hard to get a very explicit description.  SO(3) is basically SU(2), which is contained in GL(2), and even the orbits for the action of GL(2) on polynomials of degree n-1 are hard to describe once n gets large; there's machinery in GIT (geometric invariant theory) but  n=7 (the Clebsch-Igusa invariants) is about the last case you want to deal with explicitly.

Comment: I fully agree with the answer. Since for $l>1$ there are infinitely many orbits, I should have (also) asked: How many _parameters_ are needed to locate an element in orbit space. Let $M$ be a manifold where $G$ acts, then the dimension of the orbit space equals $dim(M/G) =dim(M) - dim(G) + dim(G_p)$, where $G_p$ is the principal stabilizer (= SO(2) here?). Hence $dim(S^{2n -1}/SO(3)) = 2n-3$. (Also thanks @Thomas, giving the stratum hint)

Comment: I don't understand: where does the SO(2) stabilizer come from?  I'd have thought that generically the stabilizer is finite.

Comment: Take e.g the case where $M = S^2$ and $G=SO(3)$, then $dim(S^2/SO(3) = 2 -3 +1 =0$, as it should be, since there is only one orbit. (As you mentioned, action is transitive, hence orbit space is zero-dimensional). But I'm not fully sure whether this generalizes to higher-dimensional,  unitary representations or not. (I did not fully understand the concept of the principal stabilizer, Intuitively, it tells you that some coordinates (generators) will not contribute to build up an orbit)

Comment: Yes, points on $S^2$ have an SO(2) stabilizer, but $S^2$ is not the unit sphere in a complex vector space.

Comment: Exactly, so you think the result for the dimension of the orbit space in the complex case is $2n -3$ or is this wrong?

Comment: Don't you mean $2n-4$? I also think that the stbilizer is $0$-dimensional, but am not sure of anything :)

Comment: @Peter: I think you are correct (only for $S^2$ the principal stabilizer is non trivial). See e.g [here](http://msp.org/pjm/1962/12-2/pjm-v12-n2-p23-p.pdf). Thanks to all of you!